# Use JQuery to get the index of a div with a specified background color

Tags: jquery

I have a div that contains a number of divs inside it.
The divs are used to select a number by the user.
When the select a div I make the background color of that div to green.

My problem is how do I write a JQuery selector to give 
me the index of the div that is selected ie green?

Malcolm

EDIT

```
var green = "rgb(0, 128, 0)";

function getIndex(selector) {
$(selector).each(function () {
    if ($(this).css("background-color") == green)
        return $(this).index();
});
return -1;
```

}

Comment: I think, getting the index by `$(this)` would be easier than searching for a div with green color.

Comment: It will be good if you post `html`

Comment: The code I just posted does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2L3716eb/)**

```
.green
{
    background-color:green;
    color:white;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.parent div').on('click',function(){
    $('.parent div').removeClass('green');
    $(this).addClass('green');
});

$('#btncli').on('click',function(){
    alert($('.parent div.green').index());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you changing the background color? 
if you are using $(".yourdiv").css("background-color","green")
You should create a css class instead.

```
.selected{
     background-color: green;
}
```

And then add that class

```
$(".yourdiv").addClass("selected")
```

After that, you only need to call the selector like so:

```
$(".selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the background color is applied with a class so:

```
$("div.green-color").index();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a class to "select" a div, then apply styling to that class to make the background clean. Then you can just select the element by the class like this:

```
$('.my-class')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="userselect"> </div>
      <div class="userselect"> </div>
      <div class="userselect"> </div>
      <div class="userselect"> </div>
      <div class="userselect"> </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
userselect{
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:yellow;
        border:1px solid black;
        margin:5px;
    }
    .selected{
        background:green;
    }
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".userselect").on("click",function(oEvent){
   $(".userselect").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
    alert("you clicked : "+$(this).index());
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y7krvngn/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this one...

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $("div").css("background","none");
    $(this).css("background","green"); 
    var index = $(this).index();
    alert(index);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/9zapccLL/1/)